# android studio - how to call specific button inside array Adapter

Tags: android

How to identify the button inside in the array which display 10 times in parent view? When i click the button in the first item another button well also clicked.

I have this code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemView itemView = (ItemView)convertView;
        itemView.setItem(getItem(position));

        TaskHolder holder;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = ItemView.inflate(parent);
            holder = new TaskHolder();
            holder.uploaded_img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
            holder.btn_upload_img = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_attach_photo);
            itemView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (TaskHolder) itemView.getTag();
        }
        final TaskHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.btn_upload_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finalHolder.uploaded_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // Toast.makeText(c, "Ah ok...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        return itemView;
    }

    static class TaskHolder {
       ImageView uploaded_img;
        Button btn_upload_img;
    }
```

Comment: By using `setId()` and `getId()`

Comment: Can you provide a pseudo code... Thnks